# TypeScript: Advanced Method signatures - Can you explain the ternary operator in the method signature?

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain the method signature below:

```
export type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;
```

This was the answer to a question about converting a union to an intersection type in ts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/457156

However I cannot follow the method signature.

Let's break it down:

#### Ternary operator as an argument

```
(U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never)
```

is this saying "if an object is provided, then the expected argument should be a function `(k: U) => void`

#### extends

```
(U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I)
```

`infer` I presume infers the type of `I`
The rest I am completely baffled by.

Any help would be appreciated.
Here is a discussion thread that I didn't quite follow: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the first part right, let's call that one `T1`:

```js
export type T1<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never);
```

So what we have left is (with parantheses for better readability):

```js
export type UnionToIntersection<U> = (T1<U> extends (k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
```

This one is again just a usage of the ternary operator with the condition `T1<U> extends (k: infer I) => void`. The `infer` keyword allows us to let typescript infer the type at this place to use it later in the type definition. So basically this part says:

"If `T1` extends a function `(k) => void`, use the type of its parameter `k`, otherwise `never`."

So what the whole statement does (if `U` is not `never`) is, from `U` create a type `(k: U) => void` only to then infer the parameter `k`'s type, which apparently gets inferred as a very specific type, resulting in the intersection of what `U`is a union of.